# Wrapping x posts in html without leaving empty html

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop

So I'm trying to spit out unlimited numbers of posts for this wp_query, 6 at a time, each one being wrapped in `<dd>` so that it functions with my jQuery slider. The problem is, if I have exactly 6 posts, or 12 posts, I wind up with one empty `<dd></dd>` at the end. Am I doing this wrong, or is this a limitation to Wordpress?

```
<dl><!--slider container-->
    <dd><!--slide-->
        <?php $our_work1 = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'our-work',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'featured_work',
        'meta_value' => 'yes',
        ) ); ?>

        <?php $count = 1; while ($our_work1->have_posts()) : $our_work1->the_post(); ?><!-- wp_query spits out unlimited posts meeting custom post type / meta criteria -->

        <article></article><!--post stuff goes here-->

        <?php if ($count % 6 == 0){ ?><!--spits out 6 posts per slide/<dd> -->
    </dd><!--close slide-->
    <dd><!-- starts next slide with set of 6 posts -->
        <?php } $count++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?><!--ends loop-->
    </dd><!-- close set of work items-->

</dl><!--closes slide container-->
```

Answer (score 4):

check in your loop that it's the end of a group of 6 AND the current post isn't the last post.

change:

```
<?php if ($count % 6 == 0){ ?>
```

to:

```
<?php if ($count % 6 == 0 && $count != $our_work1->post_count ){ ?>
```

Comment: This would be your answer, spot on!. :)

Comment: Hmm, I ended up doing something like this:

 `<dl><?php $count = 0; while ($our_work1->have_posts()) : $our_work1->the_post(); ?>`

 `<?php if( $count%3 == 0 ) { ?><dd><?php } ?>  <!-- make it rain -->`     

  `<article>`
  `</article>`

 `<?php if( $count%3 == 2 ) { ?></dd><?php } ?>`
 `<?php $count++; ?>`       
 `<?php endwhile; ?>`    
 `<?php if( $count%2 != 0 ) { ?></dd><?php } // in case there is not a multiple of 3 posts ?>`
       
 `<?php wp_reset_query();?>`

 `</dl>`

Edit: Why can't I line break my code??

Comment: Please delete your above comment and add that information to your original question.